# Can we use angular without node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, angular, typescript

We are working with **Django** as a server framework and used **JavaScript** for client-side scripting. Now we are migrating to **Angular4**, do we need to run a **node.js** server with the existing running Django server?

Comment: No you don't need to

Comment: No - angular has no need for your back end to be a particular tech - use Django, Node, whatever

Answer (score 6):

No, Angular is basically concerned with your front-end in your case, you don't need to use Node together with Django for your back-end.

However, what you would need node for is the build process and dependencies, as Node helps in the building process of your Angular project and in the management of your dependencies, this is facilitated also with NPM.
Apart from that, Node also allows you use the port:4200 when serving using `ng serve`.... Once your project passes the development stage and you have a dist folder, you don't need the ng serve process anymore and the files within the folder are static and can be run like your normal index.html files...
I do hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is for your front-end. You can use what you want for the back-end.
You can use Node to build your sources, to convert typescript files to javascript files.